# How to use IsNull in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Following code is okey in vba;

```
Sub Macro1()

Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "General"

Range("A7").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

If IsNull(Columns("A:A").NumberFormat) = True Then
    MsgBox "Column A format is not General"
End If

End Sub
```

I am trying to convert above code to vb.net code.

Comment: If memory serves, null in vba translates to nothing in vb.net. try IsNothing instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 If IsNothing(Columns("A:A").NumberFormat) Then
      MessageBox.Show("Column A format is not General")
 End If
```